# How to properly expand an argument to the \url or \path macro?

Tags: macros, errors, urls

In the following MSE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\newcommand{\rootDir}{\$ROOTDIR}
\newcommand{\myDir}{my/dir}
\newcommand{\makeFilePaths}[3]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname dfile#1\endcsname}{%
    \rootDir/#2/#3%
  }%
  \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname ifile#1\endcsname}{%
    ../../#2/#3%
  }%
}
\makeFilePaths{test}{\myDir}{a/file/path.txt}
\newcommand{\pathText}[1]{%
  %\edef\temp{path{#1}}% Doesn't compile
  \expandafter\path\expandafter{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\dfiletest
\pathText{\dfiletest}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to produce file paths from a set of macros, and then print the resulting path using the `\path` command (but I presume `\url` works equally well). However, I can't seem to get the argument to expand properly, as the code above yields:

```
$ROOTDIR/my/dir/a/file/path.txt       <- This is what I want
\rootDir/\myDir/a/file/path.txt       <- Should be the same as above
```

I probably need to use `\edef` in some for, but I keep getting compilation errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as your paths don't contain special characters, you can do with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\newcommand{\rootDir}{\string$ROOTDIR}
\newcommand{\myDir}{my/dir}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makeFilePaths}[3]{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname dfile#1\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\edef\csname dfile#1\endcsname{\rootDir/#2/#3}%
  }%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname ifile#1\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\edef\csname ifile#1\endcsname{../../#2/#3}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\makeFilePaths{test}{\myDir}{a/file/path.txt}

\newcommand{\pathText}{%
  \expandafter\path\expandafter
}

\begin{document}

\dfiletest

\pathText{\dfiletest}

\pathText{\ifiletest}

\end{document}
```

Using `\newcommand` is not possible because, as you observe, you need `\edef`, so I employed the inner test `\@ifdefinable` for checking that the command is still available.

Note `\string$` in order to obtain an “expandable” version of the dollar sign.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works! But what's the deal with `\string$`? Why doesn't it work with just `\$` in this case?

Comment: @gablin `\$` is a very complex macro that can't survive `\edef`.